# 12v circuit with two switches

Tags: led, switches, circuit-design, led-driver

Short version - I have a led and i want to be able to turn it on with one of two switches. If switch A is on then the light is on, if switch B is on the light should be on, if both switch A and B are on then the light should be on... the only time the light should be off is if both switch A and B are off. So different to a 3 way switch.

Longer version - Switch A is actually a remote LED controller and switch B is a motion sensor. I want the LED to turn on either by the motion sensor or by the controller. I realize in this case that I wouldn't be able to turn the lights off with the remote if the motion sensor is currently active, but I'm ok with that as a limitation.

Comment: Connect the switches in parallel?

Comment: How do you do that? I'm still very new to circuits.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS5wjh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Switch connection. (b) Connection if output is high when on. [PNP transistor output.] (c) Connection if output is low when on. [NPN transistor output.]*

Comment: +1.. BE interesting to add fig d) U1 high active, U2 pulls low..

Comment: Go ahead, Trevor! ;^)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to read those diagrams. Where is a good place to start so i can translate the above into actual wiring? Like I think I understand A but the other two I'm not 100% sure on.